# How to delete redundant line breaks？

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TeXStudio.

I want to delete many redundant line breaks in my paper. I think one easy approach is searching the line breaks and then replace them with empty.

However, how can I search the line breaks? or is there any effective way?

Comment: What do you want to gain by removing line breaks? How do you define *line break*?

Comment: I just want to keep the content of one paragraph's line numbers are the same in the texstudio. But when I use the line break optionally, the contents of one paragraph will have different line numbers, although it won't  have impact on the output pdf, but I just want to move the redundant line breaks.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with LaTeX? Shouldn't it be up to the text editor?

Comment: LinTina, the linebreaks are a great thing. Keep them. You will find errors easier.

Comment: Actually, just how to search the line breaks in Latex? In Word it is "^p"

Comment: yes, they are important, but some of them are redundant, so I just want to search one paragraph and delete the redundant ones.

Comment: You don't mean to search it in LaTeX, but rather in your text editor (in your case, it is the one used by TeXStudio.) You should go to its documentation for it.

Comment: That is a matter how you marked up your source, but usually it should be `\n` for a simple line break and `\n\n` for two consecutive ones (blank line in between).

Comment: Can you give concrete examples of what redundant line breaks are to you, and also the desired output?

Comment: @LinTIna I have the same problem as you—could not find an answer, yet. In principle, the question is not directly about LaTeX, but as so many LaTeX users edit with TexStudio, it is indirectly relevant. Looking forward to an answer!